# Quelle serait une façon plus élégante d'écrire "Il se sert des cabines de bronzage comme moyen de luminothérapie"

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation, style-de-rédaction

Je cherche une phrase exprimant la même idée mais de manière plus élégante.

- Il se sert des cabines de bronzage comme luminothérapie. (Sans le terme "moyen").
- Il se sert des cabines de bronzage pour sa luminothérapie.

Merci.

Comment: Il ferait bien d'arrêter...

Comment: Il a sa dose de lumière et il bronze. Que demander de plus ?

Comment: @Damien Un mélanome ?

Comment: @jlliagre C'est toi le docteur !

Comment: @Damien https://www.anses.fr/fr/content/cabines-de-bronzage-l%E2%80%99anses-rappelle-le-risque-av%C3%A9r%C3%A9-de-cancer-de-la-peau

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Les cabines de bronzage font pour lui office de dispensateur de séances de luminothérapie.

Answer (score 5):

Les cabines de bronzage lui servent de luminothérapie.

Answer (score 1):

> Les cabines de bronzage lui permettent d'assouvir ses besoins de luminothérapie.

Ou moins formel, et avec une métaphore jouant sur l'addiction éventuelle:

> Les cabines de bronzage lui dispensent sa dose quotidienne/hedbdomadaire/mensuelle de luminothérapie.